# facebook app is misconfigured for mobile access

Tags: facebook

Got this error when trying to use a my Facebook app on an iPad with Safari.

"mobile version of app is unavailble because it is misconfigured for mobile access"

The app works fine when used in a Safari browser on a desktop. Anyone a suggestion for a solution?

Only see this option in the settings of the app "Mobile Web URL"  which has the same value as my "site URL".

Comment: Same problem!! [I opened a bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/290132151053886)

Comment: Try deleting the 'App Domains' field. Leave that field blank and test it. lmk!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found if using authorization, I had to use m.facebook.com/authurl rather than www.facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SSL and visit https://apps.facebook.com or https://m.facebook.com on a mobile device, and your mobile URL is http:// (not https://) then you receive this error. I imagine the same happens through the Facebook iPhone app if secure browsing is enabled.

Adding the trailing slash at the end of my URL also seemed to help, but it may have been the above SSL issue confusing me.